# How to solve "make" issue while cross-compiling on the ubuntu

Tags: command-line, compiling, make, cmake, makefile

I am trying to cross-compile this ([ultralytics/yolov5](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5)) project on my ubuntu machine. Since I am compiling it for my another machine "raspberry Pi" so I already installed the toolchain which is in my following path /home/master/tools-master

After cloning the "yolov5" repo, I added the `CMakeLists.txt` file in that. So I had clone this repo in a folder "YOLO" hence the YOLO folder contains the coned repo "yolov5" and "bin" folder for building make files. Within the directory `~/Desktop/YOLO/bin` when I run the following command "`cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/user/master/Toolchain-RaspberryPi.cmake ../yolov5`" It successfully build the executable file but after this when I run the "`make`" command within the `~/Desktop/YOLO/bin` I get the following error.

```
Scanning dependencies of target yolov5
[100%] Linking CXX executable yolov5
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/yolov5.dir/build.make:69: yolov5] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/yolov5.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Can you help me know since I am just on my last edge to build the binary file before transferring it into my rpi and encountering this error

Comment: Check if this helps: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html

Comment: See also here: https://blog.kitware.com/cross-compiling-for-raspberry-pi/

Comment: "cmake" command worked for me but "make" command gave me and error as mentioned above.

Comment: @HuHa I actually followed the above link only but I failed at when I wrote "make" command. If you can help me rectify the error, it would really be great. Please let me know. Thanks!